# Its correct to use .map in this case?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary, jsonplaceholder

I was all day yesterday stuck with this problem.
I have to make a slider to show images with text that come from an object.
I made a mockup of the images and text and saved it in a .json. That worked as expected.

But now I'm getting the data from Jsonplaceholder and when I do the .map method, it's not working for me.
I know the problem comes from the index side of the .map method.

What I am trying to do is that when pressing the left or right button, it shows on the screen the image and text whose 'index' matches the variable 'current'.

'Current' is fine because I see that it is updated when pressing the right-left buttons (previous-next)
but the index is not updated or does not bring a correct number and causes the function to fail.

```
const Slider = () => {
    const [current, setCurrent] = useState(0);
    const [get] = useHttpService();
    /* const [data, setData] = useState({
        title: '',
        url: '',
        text: '',
        id: ''
    });
    const length = data.length;



    useEffect(() => {
        get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos")
            .then(res => { setData(res) })
            .catch(err => console.log(err))

    }, []);

    const nextSlide = () => {
        setCurrent(current === length - 1 ? 0 : current + 1);

    };

    const prevSlide = () => {
        setCurrent(current === 0 ? length - 1 : current - 1)
    };


    if (length <= 0) {
        return <SpinnerLoader />;

    }


    else return (
        <section className="slider">
        <FaArrowAltCircleLeft className="left-arrow" onClick={prevSlide} />
        <FaArrowAltCircleRight className="right-arrow" onClick={nextSlide} />

        {data.map((slide, index) => {
            return (
                <div className={index === current ? 'slide-active' : 'slide'}
                    key={index}>

                    {index === current && (
                        <div>
                            <img src={slide.url}
                                alt={slide.title}
                                className="image" />
                            <p className="text"> {slide.text}</p>
                        </div>
                    )}
                </div>
            )
        })}
    </section>
    )
}
```

Thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you don't update your `length` variable. Also `map` will only work on iterable objects, therefore you might need to spread and wrap your response and set an empty list as the initial state of `data`.

```
const [current, setCurrent] = useState(0);
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
const [length, setLength] = useState(data.length);

useEffect(() => {
  fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos")
      .then(res => { 
        setData([...res.json()]);
        setLength(data.length);
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err))

}, []);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.
It solved my problem that since yesterday had me stuck!!

Comment: No problem. Would you mind upvoting and marking the answer as the correct one?

Comment: i did but cause im new here, stack didn show my vote